# Two Python Scripts Through Task Scheduler

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks

I've been struggling to find information on multiple scripts.  I have two python scripts set to run at the same time (two different scripts).  Will they compete with each other or will it simply just open two instances and perform both of them?  I just want to make sure they both run and one doesn't cannibalize the other.  Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is, that you don't have to be afraid of "cannibalism". Your computer is able to handle them in parallel. I hope you forgive me, that I'm not going to explain to you in detail, how you processor is doing that as it would be to much to write.

Hope it helps you. Have a nice day!

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear python and cmd prompt could care less, as I need to run quite a few jobs that run each hour.  Thanks for the info (details weren't necessary)!

Answer (score 0):

If you time running of your scripts from **cron** both scripts are run regardless of other script's state.

**If those scripts use shared resource(s)** you have to check, that those are not run at the same time. I did check for this in my previous job for a single script. You can use grep results in Python **subprocess** to count how many times either of scripts are mentioned in top-list (**grep** count). If the resulting count is low enough, neither of the Python scripts are not run before ***this*** script was run. If I have to guess, the threshold *"number of script instances found in top"* is four in your case. Could be three ( top, cron , subprocess(top) ). Exit the code, if other script (or this script) was already running when this script was executed. For single script threshold value is 3.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, as long as they're not pulling from a shared source (i.e. fighting for the resource) I should be fine.  Due to the fact that python and cmd prompts don't care how many times I run something, I should be fine?

Comment: Yes, sure. But for example if those scripts are accessing same database tables or data streams, than this might be an issue.